# iPhone: All animation stopped working after a while

Tags: ios, objective-c

I've gotten some strange behavior lately. All animation suddenly stops working sometimes. 
Sometimes everything runs smooth, and other times this happens. Pushing and popping views just snaps into place, `UITableView` cellrow animation doesn't work.

The app uses a lot of background threads so maybe there is something in there?

I can't really post code since I don't know where the problem is.

Has anyone had the same problem?

Comment: How are you animating your views?  Show us some code.

Comment: Are you getting any strange log messages?

Comment: I'm animating some objects in the views, but mostly pushing other view controllers. No strange log messages

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I've been having the same problem, and I'm stumped.

Comment: Hey did you guyz able to find it.Its happening too frequently in iOS7 for me?? any help??

Comment: I just had the same issue, but it was a one-off and I can't get it to happen again. I inspected the view layer properties and couldn't find anything. I noticed completion blocks were being called immediately after the animations blocks, just like I had set all my durations to 0.

Answer (score 4):

Could that be you attempting to update UI/animate in different background threads?

Try?

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
  // code to update ui or start animation
});
```

Comment: Yes, that is the case, never launch any UI update in another thread than main.